# this.state.array.map is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I have declared an array of objects in the state that represent TextInput fields. Now I want to add value onChangeText of my inputs but as soon as I try to write something on the input I get the error: 'this.state.sede_array is not a function'. I did console.log of the array and I see that only the first letter of my input is added to the value property and then the error fires up. Please help to figure out what is happening.

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sede_array:[
        {id:1, value:null},
        {id:2, value:null},
        {id:3, value:null},
      ]

    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.sede_array)
    let sede_list= this.state.sede_array.map((val, key) => {
      return(
      <View key={key}>
        <Text style={styles.titolo}>Indirizzo Sede 
        {this.state.sede_array[key].id}</Text>

      <TextInput style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={value => {
          sede_array[key].value = value;
          this.setState({sede_array})
        }}
      />
      </View>
    )});
```

Comment: Please read this [Type​Error: "x" is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are clobbering your array.  Inside the onChangeText event handler, you are setting state; but do you know what the value is?  You use `sede_array` without (this.state) as a prefix.  I'm assuming sede_array variable doesn't exist globally, thus it would assign 'undefined' to this.state.sede_array when you call setState().  Since setState will trigger another render, on that render cycle it would crash because this.state.sede_array would be undefined.  You can fix this by adding `this.state.` infront of sede_array inside onChangeText.